# How to find IP Assigned to my PC by Router using C#

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming

My PC is connected to a WiFi Network. And I want to get the IP-Address assigned(to my PC) by WiFi-Network device(router or something).
OR might I say, I want to find IP-address of my PC over a network.

Actually, my PC has more than one network adapters created (3 Ethernet adapters and 1 WiFi-adapter).

I tried following code:

```
IPHostEntry localHostEntry = Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName());
string myIP = localHostEntry.AddressList[0].ToString();
```

But it returns: **192.168.138.1**

While IP assigned to my PC by WiFi-network-device is: **192.168.1.21**

**192.168.138.1** is the IP of my Ethernet adapter.

Comment: What do you get if you change it to `AddressList[1]` or `[2]`? <hint>

Comment: There are actually 4 IPv4 address in my PC. AddressList[3] returns the IP that is assigned by router. So I wrote a piece of code to always pick-up the last IP from AddressList[ ]. But I'm not sure if my required IP will always be at the last position.